# iPad app to mashup music

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a simple app that will just let me load tracks from my music library, chop some clips out of them, and assign those clips to a trigger pad. So then I can create "mashups" by holding down different combinations of trigger pads.

Any possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- [DM1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dm1-the-drum-machine/id431573951)
- [iMaschine](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/imaschine/id400432594)
- [DrumOn](https://itunes.apple.com/app/drum-on/id642348750?mt=8#)
- etc.

I have tested iMaschine years ago. I was very satisfied at the time. I'm not sure whether this App is still maintained. I have heard very good things about DM1, never really got the chance to test it though.